# Sorting a file in Python by columnar patterns

Tags: python, sorting, pattern-matching

I have the following type of file to deal with via Python:

```
key1 value1 value3 value5
key2 value2 value6
key3 value1 value5
key4 value4 value6 value5
key5 value4 value5 value6
key6 value3
....
keyN value5 value1
```

Keys are all unique, and there are only 6 possible values, but they appear in any order, and there can be any non-zero number of them (between 1 and 6) associated with each of the keys.

Is there any way to sort this file in such a way that we determine the number of lines with exactly the same pattern of values, i.e. how many lines that have pattern "value1 value3 value5"? how many lines with patter "value2 value6", etc.?
In the above example, the lines starting with key4 and key5 (or key3 and keyN) should be counted as the same pattern.

Output should be the same file resorted in a way described above.

I am completely stumped on how to do this...any help would be much appreciated! Thank You.

Comment: What is the expected output for the given input file?

Comment: @falsetru It should be the same file resorted in a way I describe, i.e. values follow expected pattern from value1 to value6 (btw, the values aren't numerical, but known character strings). The rows with most columns should be at the top of sorted file, while the key:single value pairs should be at the very bottom. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a clever key-function and use the normal function for sorting.

```
def key_length_match(x):
    # only number of values is important
    xs = x.split()
    return len(xs)

def key_unorderd_match(x):
    # only the occurence of values is important
    xs = x.split()
    return (len(xs), set(xs[1:]))

def key_exact_match(x):
    # exact ordering of values is important
    xs = x.split()
    return (len(xs), xs[1:])

lines = (l.strip() for l in open('input.txt', 'r'))
lines = sorted(lines, key=key_unorderd_match, reverse=True)
for l in lines:
    print l
```

Comment: clever key-function it is! i'll play around with it some more, but i can sense it is the correct approach right away. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider converting each line to a list that contains a key in the first entry and a secondary list of values in the second.  Then, you can do something like this:

Loop over the lines and sort the entries in each line's list of values.

Then, sort the lines by the sort order of a concatenation of the key and all the values for each line.

Finally, make a list of value lists for each key and sort those in reverse order of that list length.

I have no doubt that there are many possible ways to get this result, some possibly more efficient than I have described.  You might find some inspiration from this discussion of sorting in Python:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Edit: Thomas B.'s answer is a great example of how to implement such sorts (and cleaner than shuffling the actual data structure around as my answer implies) but you'll have to do his three sorts in the right order to get the result you are looking for, and his code only implements one of the three.